# Map path in Quartz.net in ASP.NET & C#

Tags: asp.net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, server.mappath

I am using Quartz.Net in Asp.Net C# to schedule my task. I want to write to a file, when I try without the `MapPath` it's writing to the file as expected (Hello world).

Here is the code what I wrote. I have tried `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` and `Server.MapPath`. It's simply writing the file without any content.

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("destination_actualPath\\hello1.txt", true);
    file.WriteLine("Hello world " + Server.MapPath("../Data"));
    file.Close();
}
```

Yes this folder `Data` do exist in my project directory. This function is inside the `IJob` class. If I write a new method (other than execute) it's writing to the file (hello world and path), it's not writing any content to the file if it's inside this `Execute` method.

Comment: "Not working" is not a proper problem description. Please read [ask] and provide all relevant information and your research. Also, I hope you realize web servers can't write to the client's desktop. It's working during development because your machine acts both as server and client at the time.

Comment: writing to the desktop is not the problem. The problem is that reading the path `Server.MapPath("../Data")`

Comment: I am asking what the problem **is**. What do you expect to happen, what actually happens?

Comment: I want to write the `Server.MapPath("../Data")` to my file hello1.txt. It's creating the file hello1.txt if not exist, but it's empty no content inside, even "Hello world" is not printed

Comment: I understand that. Please tell what this code actually does. We can't give you an answer if you don't explain what is happening.

Comment: This is part of a project I am working on, I need to schedule an event every day. I wrote a method what should be scheduled and it's executing if I try a simple method call. But when I try to schedule it using Quartz.Net. It did not work.  My task contains a lot of `HttpContext` context. I found out this is why my method was not working, so I am trying this simple example

Comment: Listen. We cannot answer "did not work" and "was not working". **What exactly is happening**? Any exception, any output, is the file being written somewhere else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115601/discussion-between-saai-and-codecaster).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

`file2.WriteLine("Hello World " + System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Data"));`

`HttpContext` is not allowed in Quartz.net, so we have to use `HostingEnvironment` instead. Here we usually refer virtual path using `~`, not `../`. I guess this is your mistake.

Answer (score -1):

you can use System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath method.

Comment: I tried both System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath and httpcontext.current.server.mappath

Comment: it's not useful in this question